# Event is firing Two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am binding `onclick` event to parent as well as child (same method). Event is getting fired two times How to avoid this?

```
<div id="sparentId" onclick="javascript:somemethod()" >
  <button id="childId" onclick="javascript:somemethod()"></button>
</div>
```

Onclick of Div the event is getting fired two times.

Comment: On the child event, put `preventDefault()` maybe?

Comment: you have to stop propagation of event or as click event bubbles, just bind it to parent. You could still targeting clicked element using `event.target` inside handler. FYI, as you are using jQuery, you should use jQuery to bind events

Comment: I think this is a good question for newbies.

Comment: A good question but worthless without the javascript. Look up propogation, to stop bubbling, and preventing default, to override the default behavior of something if bound in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the onclick event is showing twice, is because there is something called event bubbling in JavaScript.

Take a look at the following:

[image: Bubbling]

This image shows that, if the `<img>` was clicked, the event would "bubble" up to the `<p>` tag, then to the `<div>`, then to the rest of the document. If there was an onclick event on the `<p>` tag, and even if the `<p>` tag was not clicked (but the `<img>` was), the event would necessarily "bubble" all the way up the DOM, and would still continue when an event was fired on the `<p>` tag (in other words, if you also had an `onclick` event on the `<div>`, then that would fire as well.

So what you should do is this:

```
<div id="sparentId" onclick="javascript:somemethod()" >
  <button id="childId"></button>
</div>
```

In other words, as I explained above, you wouldn't need the extra onclick event handler in your button anymore, because when your button is clicked, the event bubbles up to the parent div, which would fire that event.

If you want to use your original HTML code, that's fine as well - just add this:

```
function somemethod(evt) { // the method you run
  // some code
  evt.stopPropagation(); // stops bubbling
}
```

This effectively stops the event from bubbling up your DOM tree.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<button id="childId" onclick="javascript:somemethod(event)"></button>
```

**JS code**

```
function somemethod(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is getting called twice because you are calling it twice, i.e. once in the div click and once in the button click. the button is already inside the div.

```
<div id="sparentId" onclick="javascript:somemethod()" >
   <button id="childId" onclick="javascript:somemethod()"></button>
</div>
```

try

```
 <div id="sparentId">
    <button id="childId" onclick="javascript:somemethod()">Click Me</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use 

event.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

Comment: why not just `event.stopPropagation();` ?